# UICollectionView cellForItemAt not get called when I use a UICollectionView inside a UITableView cell on iOS 14

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I know it sounds repetitive and millions of questions asked like this but when I use a collectionView inside a tableView cell on iOS 14, the collectionView cellForItemAt function is not called, it works on iOS 12.

[I attached a demo project for it.](https://www.mediafire.com/file/lipttn4qbe75ry0/demo2.zip/file)

here is my tableView cell which has a collectionView inside i:

```
 class ServicesTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var parentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    var items = [String]()
    var data: ServiceRow?
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        collectionView.frame.size = CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: 50)
        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "ServiceFilterCell", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ServiceFilterCell")
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func fill(with data:ServiceRow) {
        items = data.items?.compactMap({$0.name}) ?? []
        parentView.backgroundColor = .clear
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension ServicesTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell { // <= This guy is not called
        let data = items[collectionView.tag]
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ServiceFilterCell", for: indexPath) as! ServiceFilterCell
        cell.fill(title: data, isSelected: false)
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 80, height: 40)
    }
}
```

here is my parent class tableView cellForRowAt:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ServicesTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ServicesTableViewCell
        cell.collectionView.tag = indexPath.section
        cell.fill(with: services[indexPath.section])
        cell.frame.size = CGSize(width: cell.frame.width, height: 50)
        cell.collectionView.reloadData()
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        return cell
    }
```

here is a screenshot for Tarun Tyagi answer:

[image]

Finally, the problem was that the xib file for tableViewCell was conformed to collectionViewCell when I created it, so I created a tableViewCell one & now everything works fine!

Comment: Please provide updated link for the source code that has collectionView of non-zero width/height.

Comment: @ Tarun Tyagi, I updated the attached file. I added a second collectionView on the bottom of the tableView to make sure there is nothing wrong with the collectionView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your layout code and make sure that **at run time** `UICollectionView` has a non-zero size (**both width & height must be > 0**).

In case any of `width`/`height` is zero, it doesn't need to display anything and hence it won't call your dataSource implementation for `cellForItemAt:`.

You can use `View Hierarchy Debugger` to check `UICollectionView`'s `width`/`height` values at run time.

Comment: Thanks, after I check it, I found out the collectionView parent View has a small size which led to not showing collectionView so you were right, but even if I removed that parent view & now cellForItemAt is calling fine but still, collectionView does not has any cell in the debug View Hierarchy. I added a screenshot to my question.

Comment: I found the problem! Thanks a lot for your help  